# Issues with if-statement adding players with `is-inactive` class to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, if-statement, input

## Problem

**The maximum number of players for each position is:**

- 2 out of 4 goalies
- 6 out of 15 defencemen
- 12 out of 31 forwards

I've gotten to the point where I'll click on a hockey player and that name gets added to a input field in a form, but if you already have two goalies selected, ie has a class of `is-active` and then click on one of the other two unselected players with the default `is-inactive` class, that name will still be added into an input when there should **only** be two goalies max. And unfortunately, this is also the case with the defencemen and the forwards too.

## Goal

When `starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders` or `starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen` or `starredForwards === maxFowards` the names of players that **do not** have not been selected of that specific position and do not have an `is-active` class should not be added to any input in the form.

### scripts.js

```
    function countSelected() {
        $(".player").on("click", function(){

            // Checks if the maximum number of players have been selected
            // If so, return false and then do nothing
            // If not, the class will toggle from `is-inactive` to `is-active`
            if ($(this).find(".picked.is-inactive.full").length > 0) return false;
            $(this).find(".picked").toggleClass("is-inactive is-active");
            $(".player").removeClass("not-picked");
            $(".player").not(":has(.is-active)").addClass("not-picked");

            // Count the number of players with stars
            var starredGoaltenders = $(".player--goalie").find(".picked.is-active").length;
            var starredDefencemen = $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked.is-active").length;
            var starredForwards = $(".player--forward").find(".picked.is-active").length;

            console.log(starredGoaltenders, starredDefencemen, starredForwards);

            // The number of starred players for each position cannot exceed the following numbers
            var maxGoaltenders = 2;
            var maxDefencemen = 6;
            var maxFowards = 12;

            // If the number of starred players hits its max, a class of `is-completed` is adding to the corresponding checkmark to indicate that the task has been completed
            if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders) {
                $(".checkmark--goalie").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--goalie").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            } else {
                $(".checkmark--goalie").removeClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--goalie").find(".picked.is-inactive").removeClass('full');
            }

            if (starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen) {
                $(".checkmark--defencemen").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            } else {
                $(".checkmark--defencemen").removeClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked.is-inactive").removeClass('full');
            }

            if (starredForwards === maxFowards) {
                $(".checkmark--forward").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--forward").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            } else {
                $(".checkmark--forward").removeClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--forward").find(".picked.is-inactive").removeClass('full');
            }

            // If all the conditions are met show the submit vote button
            if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders && starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen && starredForwards === maxFowards) {
                $(".btn--submit").show();
                $(".btn--submit").addClass("slideLeft");
            } else{
                $(".btn--submit").hide();
                $(".btn--submit").removeClass("slideLeft");
            }
        });
} countSelected();


// Every time a player is clicked, note the name of the player
$(".player").on("click", function(){
    var playerNames = [];
    $("input:text").each(function(i, t) { playerNames.push(t.value) });

    if ($(this).find("picked.is-active")) {
        var playerName = $(this).find(".player__name").html();
        var index = playerNames.indexOf(playerName);

        if (index == -1) // Add player
            $("input:text:eq(" + playerNames.indexOf("") + ")").val(playerName);
        else // Remove player
            $("input:text:eq(" + index + ")").val("");
    } else {
        $("input").val("");
    }
});
```

### index.html - Snippet includes form and one out of the 60 available players to be clicked on

```
<form id="form">
   <input type="text" name="p1"  id="p1">
   <input type="text" name="p2"  id="p2">
   <input type="text" name="p3"  id="p3">
   <input type="text" name="p4"  id="p4">
   <input type="text" name="p5"  id="p5">
   <input type="text" name="p6"  id="p6">
   <input type="text" name="p7"  id="p7">
   <input type="text" name="p8"  id="p8">
   <input type="text" name="p9"  id="p9">
   <input type="text" name="p10" id="p10">
   <input type="text" name="p11" id="p11">
   <input type="text" name="p12" id="p12">
   <input type="text" name="p13" id="p13">
   <input type="text" name="p14" id="p14">
   <input type="text" name="p15" id="p15">
   <input type="text" name="p16" id="p16">
   <input type="text" name="p17" id="p17">
   <input type="text" name="p18" id="p18">
   <input type="text" name="p19" id="p19">
   <input type="text" name="p20" id="p20">
   <button class="btn btn--submit" type="submit"><img src="src/img/ballot-alt.png" class="image--ballot">Submit Vote</button>
</form>
<div class="player player--forward year--2000 year--2010">
   <div class="tooltip">
      <p class="tooltip__name">Mark Stone</p>
      <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Winnipeg, Man.</p>
      <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 2008-2012</p>
      <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
         <div class="stats__group stats--games">
            <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
            <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">232</p>
         </div>
         <div class="stats__group stats--goals">
            <p class="stats__header">G</p>
            <p class="stats__number stats__number--goals">106</p>
         </div>
         <div class="stats__group stats--assists">
            <p class="stats__header">A</p>
            <p class="stats__number stats__number--assists">190</p>
         </div>
         <div class="stats__group stats--points">
            <p class="stats__header">Pts</p>
            <p class="stats__number stats__number--points">296</p>
         </div>
         <div class="stats__group stats--penalties">
            <p class="stats__header">Pim</p>
            <p class="stats__number stats__number--penalties">102</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="player__headshot player--mstone">
      <div class="picked is-inactive"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
   </div>
   <p class="player__name">Mark Stone</p>
   <p class="player__position">Forward</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, you're likely to receive a better response if you can trim your code down to just the stuff that's relevant to us - see [the help center article on MCVEs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details about how go about improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, the easiest way to approach this problem is to repopulate all your inputs every time someone clicks on a player, rather than trying to populate each input once. This means you can keep your application state in a simple, easily understood data structure that is independent of your DOM/UI, rather than having to consult the DOM each time something new happens.

This is how I would probably write it.

```
var players = [
        {name: 'Ovechkin', type: 'F'},
        {name: 'Dubnyk', type: 'G'}
        // your complete player list goes here
    ],
    selectedPlayers: []; // these are the players the user has chosen


var getCurrentPlayerCount = function (playerType) {
    // return the number of players currently selected of one type
    return selectedPlayers.reduce(function (count, player) {
        if (player.type === playerType) return count + 1;
        return count;
    }, 0);
}

var selectPlayer = function (player) {
    // You call this when someone clicks on a player
    var currentForwardCount = getCurrentPlayerCount('F')
        currentDefenceCount = getCurrentPlayerCount('D'),
        currentGoalieCount = getCurrentPlayerCount('G');

    // Do nothing (or show a UI message) if someone goes over their
    // player-type limit
    if (player.type === 'F' && currentForwardCount > 12) return;
    if (player.type === 'D' && currentDefenceCount > 6) return;
    if (player.type === 'G' && currentGoalieCount > 2) return;

    // If you get here, it means the player can be added, so add
    // it to the user's list
    selectedPlayers.push(player);

    updateUI();
}
```

I'm not including `updateUI` here. You can work that out on your own.

If you need to support IE 8 or any other browser that does not support `Array.prototype.reduce`, you will need to do `getCurrentPlayerCount` differently.

Comment: That's seems really helpful, I'm just curious how this will affect/replace parts of my current code snippet

Comment: It would require thorough changes, but in my experience you will end up with a LOT less code. Having written **exactly** this kind of app before, the `updateUI()` function would have two parts: 1) Loop through your player list and update the CSS classes based on whether the player is selected; 2) Loop through your `input` elements and add the player names that are in the the user's list. The code should be probably half as long and way easier to think about. See this answer on [loose coupling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868627/why-should-a-web-architecture-be-loosely-coupled)